# Remove special symbols except apostrophes u+2019 using Regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, non-ascii-characters

From user input, I have a string of names that contains special unicode characters. I'm using Python 2.7.

Ex:

```
Panzdella*, Meslone‡, Pezzeella, Rossssi, Pastooori, Perfeetti, D’Erriico†, Puunta*, and d’Ischaia.
```

I want to remove all special characters except * and the curly apostrophe (’).

Here's what I'm doing:

```
import re

authors = raw_input('enter authors to clean characters: ')

# old code authors = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 - \,\*-\u2019]', '', authors)

#new suggestion
authors = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,*\u2019-]', '', authors)
print authors
```

The result does not preserve the curly apostrophe ’(u+2019).

How can I provide the curly apostrophe exception using regex?

Comment: Looks like you just need to make sure the hyphen does not create a range in the character class: `authors = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,*\u2019-]', '', authors)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still not getting the apostrophes in my results.

Comment: Are you sure you use `r` with the pattern? Do you write it in 1 line or split across several?

Comment: Thanks. I pasted your exact line in there on separate lines. Total 4 lines. 

`import re

authors = raw_input('enter authors to clean characters: ')

authors = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,*\u2019-]', '', authors)

print authors`

Comment: Are you sure it is Python 3? You are using `print authors`, not `print(authors)`

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I am new to programming. I thought I had 3, but I have 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes on the former pattern you used:

- `space` + `-` + `space` just matched a space as the hyphen created a range from space to space
- `*-\uXXX` was also trying to make a range, and that is not what you wanted.

To avoid issues with literal hyphens in a character class, put them at the start or end:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,*\u2019-]
```

Now, since you are using Python 2.7, the strings are byte arrays there, and in order to work with Unicode, they always must be converted (en/decoded) to/from UTF8.

Here is a way to make it work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
authors = "Panzdella*, Meslone‡, Pezzeella, Rossssi, Pastooori, Perfeetti, D’Erriico†, Puunta*, and d’Ischaia."
authors = re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,*\u2019-]', u'', authors.decode('utf8'), 0, re.UNICODE).encode("utf8")
print authors
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SuQPE6)

Output: `Panzdella*, Meslone, Pezzeella, Rossssi, Pastooori, Perfeetti, D’Erriico, Puunta*, and d’Ischaia`

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful answer! I was wondering what was so wrong with my regex.

Comment: You should think about migrating to Python 3 that supports Unicode strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
authors  = re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,*\u2019-]', '', authors)
```

Make sure to keep hyphen at last or first position in character class.

**Output:**

```
Panzdella*, Meslone, Pezzeella, Rossssi, Pastooori, Perfeetti, D’Erriico, Puunta*, and d’Ischaia
```

**Sample code:**

```
import sys, locale, re

authors = raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(True))

print re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,*\u2019-]', '', authors)
```

Comment: Hrm I still do not get the apostrophe in my output when I use that.

Comment: Try sample code in updated answer directly on your system (not on ideone)

Comment: @abubhava when I enter your new sample code, I get no response from ipython. I think it crashes. I am using python 2.7.10 I realized. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Wow and you wrote **I'm using Python 3** in your question